# How to handle v-skeleton-loader with custom v-data-table go away, if data items via props are null?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

I have the following code logic Since I want to reuse a custom-styled data-table. But I am stuck with the skeleton part as it won't go away for items with `null` value or an empty array.

**My Main component**

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetch some data")
}
```

**Child component where I have the logic**

```
<template>
<CustomTable
   :headers="userModulesHeaders"
   :items="userModulesItems"
/>
</template>

computed: {
    tableItems() {
      return this.$store.getters["some data"] ?? []
    },
}
```

**CustomTable component**

```
<v-skeleton-loader type="card" :loading="loading">
 <v-data-table
   v-bind="$attrs"
   v-on="$listeners"
  >
</v-skeleton-loader/>

computed: {
    loading() {
      return this.$attrs.items.length === 0
    }
  }
```

The skeleton finishes only if items are full but if the table items are null or empty the skeleton just keeps spinning.

How can I turn the skeleton off, if the table items are null with this logic that I have constructed in my project?

**PS:** The same result passing headers and items via props.

Comment: You should not use the nullish operator `??` when returning `tableItems`

Comment: @IVOGELOV It throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null without ```??```

Comment: In the end, I decided to have a vuex loading state for every api call that data will be shown in the data table. Instead of ```computed: {
    loading() {
      return this.$attrs.items.length === 0
    }
  }``` I am keeping the vuex getter in the computed here where I pass the name of the module and getter as a string via props in the CustomDataTable component

Comment: You said that the loader must be visible only when the items are non-null but have a length of zero - which is achieved with `:loading="$attrs.items && $attrs.items.length && $attrs.items.length === 0"`

Comment: @IVOGELOV I want to have the needed behavior from the skeleton. When the page is created I want the loader to be true so the skeleton can run, and when the data is filled or the data is empty I want the loader to be false so the skeleton can stop

Comment: It is a simple boolean function with 2 arguments - the length of the array and the array itself. Array can be either NULL/undefined or defined, and the length of the array can be either 0 or non-zero. This makes 4 combinations. Write them down and for each combination decide whether the skeleton should be visible or not. How complex can it be ?